# Modifying a char *const string

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers, runtime-error

I know that `const char *` is a pointer to a const char, while `char *const` is a constant pointer to a char.
I am testing this in the following code:

```
const char *s = "hello";    // Not permitted to modify the string "hello"
char *const t = "world";    // Not permitted to modify the pointer t

s = "hello2";   // Valid
// t = "world2";   // Invalid, gives compilation error

// *(s + 1) = 'a';    // Invalid, gives compilation error
*(t + 1) = 'a';       // Why does this not work?
```

The last line does not give any error, but causes the program to terminate unexpectedly. Why is modifying the string pointed to by `t` not allowed?

Comment: [c - Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a "char *s" initialized with a string literal, but not "char s\[\]"? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-char-s-initialized-with-a)  (C only, not C++, somehow this question has both tags)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`t` is pointing to a *string literal* it is undefined behavior to modify a *string literal*. The C++ draft standard section `2.14.5` *String literals* paragraph *12* says(*emphasis mine*):

> Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation defined. **The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined**.

The relevant section from the C99 draft standard is `6.4.5` *String literals* paragraph *6* which says(*emphasis mine*):

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

On a typical modern Unix platform you will find *string literals* in the read-only segment which would result in a access violation if we attempt to modify it. We can use *objdump* to inspect the read-only section as follows:

```
objdump -s -j .rodata
```

we can see in the following [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95f61a4fe4a19155) that the string literal will indeed be found in the *read-only* section. Note that I had to add a `printf` otherwise the compiler would optimize out the string literal. Sample `*objdump* output:

```
Contents of section .rodata:
 400668 01000200 776f726c 64002573 0a00      ....world.%s..
```

An alternative approach would be to have `t` point to an array with a copy of a *string literal* like so:

```
char r[] = "world";    
char *const t = r ;
```

Comment: You state the standard, but you do not actually say why (how) the program terminates with an error... Just saying... Elchonon Edelson gives the actual reason, which I think is the correct answer.

Comment: @AlexisWilke The standard is meant to be platform independent and such details are platform dependent which is why the standard uses such language as undefined behavior to encompass a whole range of behaviors which include working just fine but it can not be relied on. I added more details for a typical modern unix platform.

Answer (score 3):

Although string literals in C officially have a type of `char[]` (array of `char`, not `const`), the C standard specifically states that they must be treated as non-modifiable. Compilers tend to put string literals in a read-only segment, so attempting to modify them results in an access violation.

String literals are described in section `6.4.5` of the C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011).

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the compiler error by recast it as `char*`, as in `*((char*)s + 1) = 'a';` but as it was already estated in other answers, this is undefined behaviour and will probably result in Segmentation Fault because you are editing a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test it properly, initialize the strings in a function so the initialization can be dynamic and use `strdup()` for that.

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *d1 = strdup("hello");
    char *d2 = strdup("world");

    const char *s = d1;
    char *const t = d2;

    ...

    free(d1);
    free(d2);
}
```

The d1 and d2 variables are mainly used so that the dynamic allocations can be properly freed using `free()` at the end. Also, as other answers suggest, always treat string literals as `const char *`.