# Whats the difference in these pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have trouble understanding the variations among these :

```
char* s = "string";

cout<<*s+1;
cout<<(*s)++;

cout<<*s++;
```

Comment: Have tried, say uhhhh, *running it?*

Comment: I get a segmentation fault. Probably because you are modifying a `const char *`. The first line should read: `const char * s = "string";`, and then you cannot do `*s++`. Modifying a const value is undefined behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372952/modifying-a-char-const-string

Answer (score 1):

simply speaking, “string” located in ROM area, how can you modify them ?

Answer (score 0):

`*s+1` statement adds 1 with the ASCII value of the 1st element of the string and prints it. 
And `*s` prints the 1st element of the string.

Comment: ASCII, probably not. Should say "adds 1 with the code unit value". Even if we assume, in the actual character set encoding, all codepoints are one code unit, incrementing a codepoint doesn't necessarily produce a valid codepoint. For instance, [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) has holes.